# How to abbreviate months on d3 line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two questions about d3 line graphs.

I have the following line graph:
[image: d3 line graph]

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TKHYp/8/

The data looks like this:

```
    var sampleData = [
                       ["2012-01", 2+Math.random()],
                       ["2012-02", 2+Math.random()],
                       ["2012-03", 2+Math.random()],
                       ["2012-04", 2+Math.random()],
                       ["2012-05", 2+Math.random()],
                       ["2012-06", 2+Math.random()],
                       ["2012-07", 2+Math.random()],
                       ["2012-08", 2+Math.random()]];
```

and the code to convert the date is as follows:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I tell d3 to abbreviate the months (February becomes Feb.) 
   and
2. Why does it change 01-2012 to "2012" and not "January"?

If there is no way to abbreviate the months, can someone help me change the d3 code so it simply outputs the data date as a string? This way I can write javascript code to manually parse and abbreviate the date in the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `tickformat()` function. Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKHYp/9/)

tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%b"))

More info on format specifiers: [https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat)

tickformat: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat

Comment: Did you forget to link to the jsfiddle?